# Local access to cloud files on Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I just got a Chromebook, and understand that anything in the Downloads folder is stored locally.

Let's say I am starting a new document of some kind. If I put the files in the Downloads folder, I have access when I don't have wifi. That is good. But if I drop the chromebook in a lake, I lose the files. That is bad. On the other hand, if I put the files in one of my Google Drive folders, backup is assured, but I won't have access when I don't have wifi. Or will I? I am confused about this point--are some files on Google Drive cached locally? Is there a way to guarantee this for files of interest?

To sum up, is there a way to have a file synced to Google Drive AND *ensure* it's available locally on the chromebook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and how to set it up is in the following link https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2809731.
Good luck with your Chromebook - I think I will be getting one soon!